# Granularity of data sample for multiple regression

Tags: multiple-regression

I have 10000 bricks. Each brick contains multiple physicians. I have features at brick level. I created a regression model with dependable variable as sales. Hence, I got sales at brick level in validation set. I used average /weighted average to distribute the sales at physicians level. This method works quite well and  sales number at physicians level approximate to real world numbers. We can not use physicians data in modelling due to confidentiality concerns.

A professor intimated me that my model has a fundamental flaw. I can not generalize my model at physician level when my modelling was done at brick level.

Please help me understand that how can I correct my model when I don't have physician level data? Is the real world approximation of sales number at physician level a mere coincidence, I guess so? And what is that fundamental error in my model called statistically?

Comment: "Brick"? Do you mean "block"?

Comment: Yeah. In the same sense.

Answer (score 0):

This is a case of the [modifiable area unit problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modifiable_areal_unit_problem).

I don't know of any clean ways of dealing with it absent samples of granular data.